# Recommendations for a million http requests

Tags: java, c++, php, c, node.js

I have more than one million http requests to do, and I want to use a high performance programing language to do it. I coded it using PHP, but the result was too bad. I should make cUrl requests with get method and check the response if true and the one of these million requests will response be true. What is the best programing language that can do it  fast?

Comment: Practically any programming language that has executables will do.

Comment: one million req per minute? By the way, best is relative. You should consider elaborating your user story. What do you do in those requests: database, calculation, something IO bound, or just static response?

Comment: Clarify that “one million” part.

Comment: @BasilBourque yea lol

Comment: I am not sure. But making 1 million requests for one website, I guess would take it down

Comment: If you're a skilled programmer, nothing will beat the speed of assembly language, with the sole exception of coding directly in machine language.

Answer (score 0):

Cpp will be the best solution. You can try framework like cppweb or crow. Python has a new framework named Japronto, it's screaming-fast, scalable, asynchronous.